# typing "end" inside a script to end a process started

Tags: bash

I have a script where I start it in the script but it needs "end" to be typed to shut down correctly, Is there anyway I can this from inside the script with the PID?

Answer (score 1):

For this case you can even use a here-string:

```
$ myscript <<< end
```

This will make your script read from the given string instead of `stdin`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

```
$ myscript <<EOF
  end
  EOF
```

so the above feeds everything into your process' stdin up to (but not including the line `EOF`)

Comment: So if my script is called test.sh. If I put the following line inside the script after I run the command that should work: $test.sh <<EOF ; end ; EOF